# What is the difference between 词 and 汉字?

Tags: meaning

Does 汉字 refer to the actual written character while 词 refers to the meaning conveyed by that character? Or can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

汉字 means character while 词 means word. A word can consists of a single character (which is very common in old literature), or more than one characters.